# Check for string in column but restrict for certain words

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I have a SQL procedure that checks for a certain String in a column like

```
SELECT [text_field] FROM [dbo].[tbl_a] (NOLOCK) WHERE [text_field] LIKE '%search%'
```

But how can I restrict this query to show results for `%search%` but not for `searching`?

The same applies the other way if I search for `%happy%` but not `unhappy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
SELECT [textfield] FROM [tbl_a] (NOLOCK) WHERE [textfield] like '%[^a-z]search[^a-z]%';
```

I first query

```
WHERE [textfield] like '%search%'
```

then I create a list of all words containing 'search' from that result 
Next I loop over the selected words e.g. 'searching' but not 'Researching'

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL statement selects all customers with a Country containing the pattern "search":
Why you don't use this?:

```
SELECT [text_field] FROM [dbo].[tbl_a] (NOLOCK) WHERE [text_field] = "search"
```

For more information to
[LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

**EDIT**

```
SELECT [text_field] FROM [dbo].[tbl_a] (NOLOCK) WHERE [text_field] LIKE '%search%' AND [textfield] NOT LIKE '%unhappy%'
```

Comment: because the column contains more words then just 'search' or 'happy'

Comment: So what do you want to search if you type "happy"? Do you want to search all where the  [text_field] contains "happy" but not "unhappy"!?

Comment: Ah sorry, i tought you have only one word in the column. You have to do this with the LIKE operator. Hopefully it should work for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
SELECT [field] FROM [dbo].[TABLE] (NOLOCK) WHERE [field] = "search"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
[Contains](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

```
SELECT [text_field] FROM [dbo].[tbl_a] WHERE Contains([text_field],'search')
```

This query is only available if the column is in a full text index. You have to assign full-text index to your `text-field` column .

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Comment: it might work, but i am actually querying a view, thats a bit tricky to setup, i will try